# programatically create json array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My code is

```
var arr=[];
$.post( "/reports/search", { query:'*'},function(data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i].value=data[i].name;
            arr[i].data=data[i].id;
        }

},'json');
```

I want to create a json array variable and i want the resut like below

```
arr=[ {"value":"aaa",data:"1"},
      {"value":"bbb",data:"2"},
      {"value":"ccc",data:"3"}

]
```

How to do it in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in all modern browsers:

```
var arr = data.map(function(row){return {value: row.name, data: row.id});
```

In ES6 (with deconstruction and renaming):

```
var arr = data.map(({name: value, id: data}) => ({ value, data }))
```

Comment: BTW. if you need older browsers, just do a $.map(data, function(row) {...});

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the object before you can assign to its properties:

```
var arr=[];
$.post( "/reports/search", { query:'*'},function(data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = {};
            arr[i].value=data[i].name;
            arr[i].data=data[i].id;
        }

},'json');
```

Or you can just do all 3 steps at once by using an object literal:

```
var arr=[];
$.post( "/reports/search", { query:'*'},function(data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = {
                value: data[i].name,
                data: data[i].id
            };
        }

},'json');
```